# Can connect to Oracle DB via R but can't fetch data

Tags: r, database, odbc, dbi

At work I've been trying to connect to an Oracle DB using R. I've been provided the credentials and I successfully managed to connect (using 32bits R version):

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

con <- odbc::dbConnect(drv = odbc::odbc(), driver = "Oracle dans OraClient12Home1_32bit", 
                        DBQ = "<dbq>", Uid = "<uid>", 
                        PWD = "*****")
```

Then I attempt to list tables but I end up with hundreds of `"KEYSET_100", "KEYSET_101", etc.` tables :

```
objects <- DBI::dbListObjects(con)
objects

                           table is_prefix
1    <Id> table = KEYSET_1344394     FALSE
2   <Id> table = KEYSET_31246508     FALSE
3   <Id> table = KEYSET_15797611     FALSE
4   <Id> table = KEYSET_31246691     FALSE
```

This doesn't help to recognise what is what, and worse, if I try to read any of these tables I end up with something like below which does not echo any meaningful data :

```
> dbReadTable(con, "KEYSET_1344394")
[1] KEYSET_ID LONG_VAL  STR_VAL   DBL_VAL   DATE_VAL 
<0 lignes> (ou 'row.names' de longueur nulle)
```

In the RStudio "Connections" pane, however, I see some meaningful table names which are sorted in some hierarchy.

When I try to access these directly I end up with some error (DGZ would be the "subfolder" in which the DGZ_ROAD_TABLE is available :

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM DGZ.DGZ_ROAD_TABLE'
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sql)

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2809: HY000: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-24359: OCIDefineObject n'a pas été appelé pour un type d'objet ou une référence
 
Warning message:
In dbClearResult(rs) : Result already cleared
```

Any idea what I should do to make this successful ?

I've been reading about what schemes are etc. but can't figure out a way to connect this knowledge to my current issue. What should I ask to my IT department, since they don't know R specifically and won't be able to help with R functions ? I have requested technical documentation (pending...) but even if I get it I'm maybe missing something in my rationale.

Thanks !

Comment: *"using 32bits R version"* is perhaps a good hint that you're using R-4.1 or older, is the reason you're using 32-bit because the Oracle driver is 32-bit only?

Comment: Exactly. The driver is my constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know Oracle, your IT guys don't know R, I don't know R nor Esri (we'll come to it later) so we make a pretty good party.

---

I searched the Internet for [KEYSET tables](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/geodatabase-system-tables-oracle.htm). Google says that these are related to **Esri** (*geographic information system software company. It is best known for its ArcGIS products*).

> Keyset tables are used by ArcGIS clients to improve query performance (...)
>
> Keyset table names are formatted as follows: `<user_schema>keyset_<process_id>` (...)

So, table named e.g. `KEYSET_1344394` *looks like* that - KEYSET followed by number that might be a process ID.

If that's so, then you actually established connection and managed to access tables, but - most probably the ones you don't really need.

---

As I said:

- I don't know R so I have no idea how to filter tables.

  - Do you? If *yes*, could you - for example - filter all KEYSET tables out so that you get list of all other tables?
- I don't know Esri nor ArcGIS so I have no idea why those temporary tables still exist (hundreds! of them!). I'd expect that they should be removed when they aren't needed any more ... On the other hand, maybe they *are* still used. I'm ignorant, I know.

---

I'm aware that this isn't really an answer to your question, but is too much to put into a comment. If it is useless, I'll remove it; say so.

Comment: Thanks for your help and thinking! Actually I haven't thought about filtering these out as I thought I was only reading keyset values... I will check that ASAP at work.

Comment: You're welcome; if it is not a problem, reply once you check it - I'm curious whether you'll manage to fix it.

Comment: Well here I am again, sorry for the delay. Filtering 3'000+ KEYSET_<id> tables leave me with only two SDE_LOGFILES and SDE_LOGFILES_DATA tables... RStudio IDE shows available tables in the viewpane and they all have a name that makes sense : however I can't read any of these (tried SQL queries, dbReadTable, etc.). My colleagues can easily do that in Python, I'll try to find some clues with them.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after many attempts I finally found a solution.
I had to pass a schema argument to `dbListTables()` to find the real table names behind each schema, and not the `KEYSET_<id>` meaningless table names...

```
tables <- dbListTables(con, schema = "AGR")
```

You might as well say that without knowing the names of the schemes in the first place I had no chance finding a solution.

To find the schemes I used `odbc::odbcListObjects(con)`.

Woof. Thanks for the help !